# Python calling method in class has no attribute/got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, class

I am new to Python and I am trying to define a simple class with attributes and one method.

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

class BondPricing:
    
    def __init__(self, price = 95.0428,par = 100,T = 1.5,freq = 2,coup_perc = 5.75,dy = 0.01,guess = 0.05):
        self.price = price
        self.par = par
        self.T = T
        self.freq = freq
        self.coup_perc = coup_perc
        self.dy = dy
        self.guess = guess
        
    def ytm(self):
        freq = float(self.freq) #cast frequency as float data type
        periods = self.T*freq #calculate number of cash flow periods
        coupon = self.coup_perc/100.*self.par/freq #calculate actual periodic coupon level
        dt = [(i+1)/freq for i in range(int(periods))] #calculate time steps in bond maturity
        #write down ytm function from bond pricing formula
        ytm_func = lambda y:sum([coupon/(1+y/self.freq)**(self.freq*t) for t in dt])+self.par/(1+y/self.freq)**(self.freq*self.T)-self.price
        return optimize.newton(ytm_func, self.guess) #find root of ytm function via Newton-Raphson 


bond1 = BondPricing()
```

When I try to call the method of the class with `bond1.ytm(price = 95.0428, par = 100, T = 1.5, coup_perc = 5.75, freq = 2)`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ytm() got an unexpected keyword argument 'price'
```

or when I try:

```
bond1.ymt()
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'BondPricing' object has no attribute 'ymt'
```

Can anyone kindly explain me what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `ytm()` function takes no argument, that's why your 1st try was wrong. And you misspelled it on the 2nd try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to call the method of the class with `bond1.ytm(price = 95.0428, par = 100, T = 1.5, coup_perc = 5.75, freq = 2)`, I get the following error:

> `TypeError: ytm() got an unexpected keyword argument 'price'`

The error is because the ytm method does not accept any arguments.
You should be passing the arguments when you intialize the class.
Example:

```
    bond1 = BondPricing(price = 95.0428, par = 100, T = 1.5, coup_perc = 5.75, freq = 2)
    # now call ytm method on the object
    bond1.ytm()
```

> or when I try: `bond1.ymt()`
> I get this error:
>
> `AttributeError: 'BondPricing' object has no attribute 'ymt'`

You have defined the method name as ytm.
You should be calling it as

```
bond1.ytm() # not bond1.ymt()
```